# Не запускается код на Raspberry-Pi 4

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, pytesseract

Код должен запуститься на Raspberry-Pi 4,но ничего не выдает. даже никакой ошибки нет. Есть идеи, в чем проблема?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
from trecker import *
import pytesseract
import re

# Размеры области машины
WIDTH = 350
HEIGHT = 600


cap = cv2.VideoCapture("C:/Users/smero/Desktop/mirea/")  # Открываем видеофайл для чтения
obj = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history=150, varThreshold=170)  # Инициализируем объект для вычитания фона
tracker = Tracker()


while True:
    success, frame = cap.read()  # Захватываем кадр из видеофайла
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))  # Изменяем размер кадра
    roi = frame[208:380, 71:546]  # Обрезаем область, в которой находится машина
    mask = obj.apply(roi)  # Применяем метод вычитания фона
    _, mask = cv2.threshold(mask, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  # Применяем пороговую фильтрацию
    cnt, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)  # Находим контуры объектов
    points = []
    for c in cnt:
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)
        if area > 1000 and area < 1300:
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            points.append([x, y, w, h])

    point = tracker.update(points)  # Обновляем точки отслеживания
    for i in point:
        x, y, w, h, id = i

        x_min, y_min = max(0, x), max(0, y)  # Определяем границы только для области машины
        x_max, y_max = min(x + w, roi.shape[1]), min(y + h, roi.shape[0])

        roi_cropped = roi[y_min:y_max, x_min:x_max]  # Выделяем область машины

        time.sleep(0.3)

        small_frame = cv2.imwrite("flip.png", roi_cropped)

        img = cv2.imread('flip.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

        # Загрузка изображения
        image_path = "flip.png"
        img = cv2.imread(image_path)

        # Увеличение размера изображения для улучшения качества
        resized_img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=1.5, fy=1.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

        # Увеличение резкости изображения
        sharpened_img = cv2.filter2D(resized_img, -1, np.array([[-1, -1, -1], [-1, 9, -1], [-1, -1, -1]]))

        # Преобразование в серый цвет
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(sharpened_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Применение порогового фильтра для улучшения четкости текста
        _, threshold_img = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

        # Применение операции расширения для увеличения жирности текста
        kernel = np.ones((2, 1), np.uint8)
        dilated_img = cv2.dilate(threshold_img, kernel, iterations=1)

        cv2.imshow('4', dilated_img)

        # Распознавание текста на улучшенном изображении
        custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6'  # Параметры конфигурации для улучшения распознавания текста
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(dilated_img, config=custom_config, lang='rus')

        characters_to_remove = ", | $ @ ^ = [ ] ' " " ; : \ / { } . “ < > "
        for char in characters_to_remove:
            text = text.replace(char, "")
        text1 = text.upper()

        text1 = text1.replace('\n', '').replace('\x0c', '')
        text1 = re.sub(r"\s+", "", text1)

        if len(text1) >= 8:
            print('\033[32m {}'.format(len(text1)))
            # проверка с bd.txt'

            file_path = 'bd.txt'  # замените на актуальный путь к файлу

            text_found = False

            with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
                for line in file:
                    if text1 in line:
                        text_found = True
                        break

            if text_found:
                print('\033[1;31;47m {}'.format(text1) + ' найден в файле' f"{'':*>190}\n")
            else:
                print(f'Текст {text1} не найден в файле.\n')
        if len(text1) >= 5:
            print('\033[32m {}'.format(len(text1)))
            print('\033[34m {}'.format(text1))


        cv2.imshow("Cropped ROI", roi_cropped)  # Выводим выделенную область на отдельное окно

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)  # Рисуем прямоугольник вокруг машины
        # cv2.putText(frame, str(id), (x, y - 1), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (255, 0, 0), 2)  # Выводим ID машины на кадр

    cv2.imshow("FRAME", frame)  # Выводим кадр с обозначенными машинами

    if cv2.waitKey(32) & 0xFF == 27:  # Ожидание нажатия клавиши ESC
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). в частности: не стоит пытаться запихивать в заголовок весь текст вопроса. там должно быть лишь краткоё ёмкое описание проблемы. а остальное - в тексте вопроса.

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста подробнее. Как вы запускаете код? И что пишется в терминале?

Comment: запускается через visual code. В терминале ничего нет, даже предупреждения от opencv. Если попробовать открыть в терминале рассбери, то тоже самое "ничего"

Comment: добавь в начале какой-нибудь print("hello"), чтобы точно знать, запускается или нет